# Home banking site request, it possible for a small web agency?

Tags: tls, banks, secure-coding

I'm working in a web agency, i have a request to made an home banking system for a little bank. I'm searching in internet for some information about security and a good pattern to start, but naturally i haven't found information. I'm a little bit confused, i know that a php web-portal is not suggested in most case (seems that php needs more work to make things secure...),so where i have to redirect my attention? Asp and iis or Jsp and Oracle? It's the same for security reasons? 
What are the standard that i must respect? Https and what else?
I'm also pretty anxious... It is really possible for a small agency to create an home banking system?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please consider hiring a professional; of course you'll have to read a metric tonne of books to tell a professional from a crook.

Comment: I doubt that you can arrive at the security needed for home banking by just reading a bit here and their. It's not primary a question of the toolkit, it's more a mindset how to do secure programming. I would suggest that you get first a deep knowledge of CSRF, XSS, Clickjacking, SQL Injection, RFI ..., read and understand the information at OWASP and let an experienced penetration tester have a look at your system before any black hats will do it. I would also suggest you to get a good layer which saves you from any troubles in case something will break (and it will probably break).

Comment: thanks for the answers, naturally i don't pretend to build up an home banking system only with the answers found in this site... I would only made me an idea, a place to start. Then i'll study all the necessary stuff , only if those stuffs don't require me an year of study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you already have experience in the field, then yes, this is too complex for a small web agency.  PHP can be used securely, but you have to know what you are doing.  As part of a small web agency, I worked on a high security system to manage a bill payment service with many similar requirements to an online banking system.  The project never reached completion due to the client running in to internal troubles with their business, however it was fully possible to do and we were making excellent progress until the client's business went under.

The problem is that if you don't already have an in-depth knowledge of secure programing and either know, or have someone who knows the banking regulations you need to follow, producing a technically and legally compliant solution is going to be exceptionally time consuming and difficult.

The project I worked on only stayed on schedule because the client understood the legal requirements for the system and I knew how to securely implement such features already.  (The need for such a secure developer was actually what got me involved with that company in the first place.)

If you want to try taking on such a job, you will want to find someone local who has a background in writing secure software and work with them on the project.  It isn't all that difficult to implement a secure site with basic functionality, but it does require a lot of knowledge and understanding that goes beyond what we can provide in an online Q/A format.